# Custom build with core-js

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm trying to create a custom build with core-js.  Per the documentation, I first ran

```
npm i core-js && cd node_modules/core-js && npm i
```

which seemed to be fine.  Then, also per the docs I tried

```
C:\GIT\coreJS_Custom\node_modules\core-js>npm run grunt build:es6.array.from -- --library=on --path=custom uglify
```

and lots of variations on that theme.  It seems to run briefly, with no output at all, and I can't seem to find any generated file.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, the above commands were run on the Windows 8.1 cmd terminal.

What's particularly interesting (and frustrating) is that running this

```
C:\GIT\coreJS_Custom\node_modules\core-js>npm run grunt kjhgjhghkghh
```

Similarly runs briefly and then seems to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what my root problem is, but for me, running the grant task on its own, without npm run did the trick

So something like this should be the final product.

```
C:\GIT\coreJS_Custom\node_modules\core-js>grunt build:es6.array.from --library=on --path="es6-array-from-build-min2" uglify
```